# Bottleneck and bad style code

Tags: c++, optimization, mmap

I wrote a program and I have a performance problem.

The bottleneck is this function:

```
void getlinesplit(const char *file, unsigned int &pos, tline &vline)
{
    vline.clear();

    unsigned int debut_du_mot = 0;
    unsigned int i = 0;
    while (file[pos+i] != '\n')
    {
        if (file[pos+i] == '\t')
        {
            vline.push_back(std::string(file+pos+debut_du_mot,i - debut_du_mot));
            debut_du_mot = i+1;
        }
        ++i;
    }
    vline.push_back(std::string(file+pos+debut_du_mot,i - debut_du_mot));
    pos = pos + i+1;
}
```

This function is called 11 988 400 times.

`vline` is the same string vector to avoid creating and destroying a vector.

How can I improve this function?

PS: The line is composed of 1 or 2 words maximum.

Comment: Profile it, I'm betting in the push_back function. Do you initialize your vector with any size or do you use default? If you use default there must be a lot of resizing in there (and consequently reallocation)

Comment: Perhaps you could look at where this is being called from and choose a better interface. Perhaps one that doesn't involve constructing `std::string`s.

Comment: @PedroDavid I use     tline vline;    vline.reserve(2);

Comment: My bad, didn't see the clear

Comment: No problem @PedroDavid, do you think it's a good idea to have a vector of char * + size, and not a vector of string? PS the char * is a mmap file

Comment: It might be worth checking the performance difference but I don't think it should be that much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the function is not the bottleneck, but the fact that you are calling it 12 million times :-)

An obvious improvement is having a variable

```
const char* file_pos = file + pos;
```

simplifying every single access. You don't say how tline is implemented; if a line never contains more than two words then you can probably make it faster by having two std::string members instead of an array.

Comment: typedef std::vector<std::string> tline; your advice is tline become a std::pair<std::string,std::string>?

Answer (score 0):

`std::experimental::string_view` from C++17 if accessible should make that a bajillion times faster.  If not, something similar (begin/end pointer pairs or start/length).

It is also awkwardly written, but I do not see anything horrible performance wise.

Toss in some alignment/length guarantees and you could SSE optimize it, but that would be tiny next to the replacement of strings with views, and much harder.

Any benefit is likely to be limited, as the situation is probably io-bound.  Get a faster disk.